# HTACCESS Works, But php $_GET Does Not

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite, get

I have read through almost every post regarding this issue, and nothing seems to work.

I have successfully rewritten the below code, and it works just fine. The `.htaccess` file is in the `/~user/business/` folder. I use `RewriteRule ^index/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,PT]` while accessing `http://localhost/~user/business/index/155/`. However, when I try to get the variable in php, it returns nothing. The rewrite works as it does load `index.php`, but no get variables at all.

My main goal, I want to access the `id` from the code above, but nothing shows up. `<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>` Even when I try this `print_r($_GET);` the array of all get variables, it returns an empty array. I also do not want to append the query to the end of url at all.

Lots of posts have answers that work according to responses, and even when I copy them word for word, letter for letter, changing the directories and addresses, nothing seems to work.

I am using Apache 2, set up on a MAC as localhost. Is there something wrong, maybe in the php.ini file?

Comment: Is that your only rule? Is there a reason you use the `PT` flag?

Comment: It was just something I saw. I tried `NC,L` and `L,QSA` and many other combinations. I do not care on that part as long as I can access that part of the url, without having to append the query with or without QSA

Comment: None of these flags are needed.

Comment: Then how can I access my id var in my url with the Rewrite

Comment: I removed them all, and still it does not let me access via `$_GET`

Comment: If you browse directly to `http://localhost/~user/business/index.php?id=12345` does it show `$_GET['id']` correctly?

Comment: yes, thats why i figured it may be fault of the configuration of php

Comment: You might use the `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` directives in your .htaccess to output a log somewhere -- it will tell you exactly what mod_rewrite is doing as it decides what to do with the request.

Comment: "Is that your only rule?"

Comment: Yes, that is my entire .htaccess file. Also, Alex, I tried establishing a log, and it will not record anything, I know you can not add it to your htaccess file, but I added it to my .conf file tried both httpd.conf and my user.conf and nothing happened. I specified several different locations. I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: You might try _temporarily_ adding `[R=301]` to the rewrite rule, so that you can see in your browser that you're actually rewriting the URL as you think you are (do you have `RewriteEngine On`?). `/index/1234` SHOULD give you `/index.php?id=1234`. Also, "It was just something I saw" is a recipe for disaster. You **must** understand the code and flags you're using!

Comment: `[R=301]` never did anything, change the display or anything. You mis read my pervious comments, I never used what I read without the research, I read several articles on this exact same issue and none of the answers worked for me. It was not just something I had read.

Comment: Here, you know what. This is my actual code `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/index/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1` and this is the page I am accessing `http://localhost/~user/business/index/sdf3245/` The `.htaccess` file is in the `business` directory and all I want to do is to get the `$_GET['id']`. So lets not look at what I should not be doing and look at my code and my explanation and come up with a solution as to how I can fix this. My RewriteRule works, it redirects, to go back to the original, it will not let me access the `$_GET['id']` and that is all I want it to do

Comment: It has to be my server, everything I have matches up exactly to what other sources have said would fix the issue. So therefore, I guess that I will not know until I try it on an actual web server rather than just apache2 on my mac.

Comment: Alright, so I got the log, I am going to append it to my post as to the rewrite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many times trying, as much as reconfiguring the entire virtual host setup on my mac, I realized that it was a very simple error once I realized it, and it had nothing at all to do with my `.htaccess` file.

My file name was `index.php` and my rewrite was `RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]` and for some reason, it will not let me use `^index` if there is a file called `index.php`. I can name `^index` to `^page` or `^blue` or anything else but not `^index` and it will work fine.

What I realized was that my `/index.php` page can be loaded simply by typing `/index`. And therefore, was not actually a redirect, it was the stand alone page.

In order to fix this I had to add a few lines of code to my `vhost.conf` or my `user.conf` file under `<Directory "/Users/User/Sites">` file using the terminal.

```
sudo nano /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and in this, the code I had to removed `MultiViews` from the options.

```
<Directory "/Users/User/Sites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

so it now looks like this

```
<Directory "/Users/User/Sites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Once I did so, `/index.php` page can no longer be loaded by typing `/index`. And therefore, I could use the code I originally used in my .htaccess file. And all is solved in paradise. It took a lot of very hard digging and one major headache.

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Upvote for you, for solving it yourself, and taking the time to post back. Post your additional question as an edit and refer to your answer below.

Comment: Thanks :) And I just edited the answer as well, because evn my answer had a question that I just solved, and now I just saw another person with a similar issue, so off I go lol.